# Test for comparing x-intercepts of two linear regression

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, intercept

I would like to know how to compare, and then calculate significant differences, if any, between the x-intercepts of two regression lines. Practically, I should compare the values of x when y=0. I know how to compare the y-intercepts and the slopes, but I need to compare the x-intercepts. I can't reverse the position of the predictor and the dependent variable, which would allow me consider the x-intercept as y-intercept and solve the problem, because the fitted lines are different. So the predictor must be x and the dependent variable must be y.

Comment: What do you mean that the fitted lines are different? And why does that matter?

Comment: If I rightly consider my predictor as X and my dependent variable as Y and calculate the x-intercept as -y.intercept/slope I will obtain a certain value (namely 86). If I reverse the role of variables, putting the predictor as Y and the dependent variable as X, I will directly obtain the y.intercept value equal to 83. In this case the y.intercept would be the value of my predictor when dependent. variable is 0. This could change the significance between this value and that obtained from another regression line. I hope I am sufficiently clear in explaining the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I will simplify my answer by assuming that the predictors $x_i$ are fixed instead of randomly sampled, so the only variability in the data comes from the $\varepsilon_i$ (alternatively, you can view what i have below as standard errors conditional on covariates). Additionally, I will consider the case where you're comparing regressions fitted on two independent datasets, so there is no need to worry about correlations between error terms between equations. Hopefully, the approach generalizes, even if you want to relax one or both of those assumptions. In that case, it suffices to figure out how to get the standard errors for an estimator of the x-intercept from a single regression. Given my above assumptions, we have:

$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \varepsilon_i,\quad \mathbb E[\varepsilon_i | x_i] = 0,\quad \mathbb V\mathrm{ar}(\varepsilon_i | x_i) = \sigma^2$$

Given this model, we have that the x-intercept by definition is given by

$$\theta = -\frac{\beta_0}{\beta_1}$$

Given this definition of $\theta$, a fairly intuitive estimator would be to use the following procedure:

1. Fit $\hat\beta_0, \hat\beta_1$ using OLS
2. Estimate $\theta$ via $\hat\theta = -\frac{\hat\beta_0}{\hat\beta_1}$

If you have a large enough sample that $\hat\beta_0$ and $\hat\beta_1$ are reasonably precisely estimated, you can use the [delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) to show that $\hat\theta$ will be approximately normally distributed. Specifically, we have $\theta$ = f(\beta_0, \beta_1) where $f(x,y) = - x / y$, so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -\frac{1}{y}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{x}{y^2}$. Plugging this into the delta method formula, we would have that the standard errors for the estimator of $\theta$ would be given by:

$$\hat\sigma_\theta = \sqrt{\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{\hat\beta_1}&  \frac{\hat\beta_0}{\hat\beta_1^2}\end{bmatrix}\widehat{\mathbb Var(\hat\beta_0, \hat\beta_1)}\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{\hat\beta_1}&  \frac{\hat\beta_0}{\hat\beta_1^2}\end{bmatrix}^T}$$

where $\widehat{\mathbb Var(\hat\beta_0, \hat\beta_1)}$ is the variance-covariance matrix of the OLS estimates, which most software implementations of OLS should compute. For example, in R, if you fit a model (which I will call `lmod`) using lm, you can call `vcov(lmod)`.

Finally, if you wanted to test the difference between $\hat\theta$ in your two samples (which I label "1" and "2" below), you could state your null hypothesis as $H_0: \theta_1 = \theta_2$ against an alternative hypothesis, $H_1: \theta_1 \neq \theta_2$, a two sample z-test would be asymptotically valid (the reason for this is that the delta method implies that the estimators of $\theta$ in each of your two samples are asymptotically normal, so their difference will also be asymptotically normal). Specifically, you would reject if

$$\left|\frac{\hat\theta_1 - \hat\theta_2}{\sqrt{\hat\sigma_{\theta,1}^2 + \hat\sigma_{\theta,2}^2}}\right| > z_{1 - \frac\alpha2}$$

where $\hat\theta_1, \hat\theta_2$ are the estimates of $\hat\theta$ in the respective samples and $\hat\sigma_{\theta,1}, \hat\sigma_{\theta,2}$ are their respective standard error estimates.

Let me conclude with a number of caveats. First, if you are comparing two regressions on the same dataset, the above gets a lot more complicated to do. In particular, the denominator of the z-statistic I am using above is implicitly making use of the fact that the OLS slopes from the two samples are not correlated with each other. If that assumption is problematic, I would consider thinking about your regressions within a [SURE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seemingly_unrelated_regressions) framework. Second, the delta method approach for standard errors I propose may not work very well if your sample is small, or if $\beta_1$ is too close to 0, due to the fact that $1/x$ blows up as $x \to 0$. In those cases, you might consider alternative methods for constructing standard errors like a [bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)). Finally, in moderate sized samples, the estimate for $\theta$ I propose may be fairly biased, so you might consider a bias-correction method to improve your estimates of $\theta$ like a [jackknife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackknife_resampling).

Comment: You might find that a more stable procedure to compare the two estimates is based on constructing a confidence interval for $\hat \beta_1^{(1)}\hat \beta_0^{(2)} - \hat \beta_0^{(1)}\hat\beta_1^{(2)}$ because it does not require a potentially poor approximation of the ratios.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, but unfortunately, I am not so experienced in statistics and I am struggling a bit. Your hypothesis about predictor is actual, indeed it is fixed, so the two regressions have the same x. Also, my samples are very small, just 6 points each. 
Calculating a x-intercept for every regression line I would have 2 values, but I do not know how to perform a bootstrapping, which based on your assumptions it seems the more appropriate method. Also, my software doesn't support this function. I wonder if I could implement this calculation in an excel spreadsheet.